# How to avoid assignments while comparing in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to compare a variable to a value and accidently ended up using '=' in place of '==' hence the code looked like:

```
var test = 1;
if(test = 2) {
 console.log(test);
}
```

instead of:

```
var test = 1;
if(test == 2) {
 console.log(test);
}
```

I assume the value was successfully assigned to the variable , hence the condition returned truthy and `console.log()` was executed. Is my assumption correct? What is a good coding practice to avoid such mistakes besides [Yoda Condition reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions)

Comment: It's called bench checking (self review) or code review (another person or group checks your code).

Comment: Your assumption is correct. For the rest, I would just recommend paying attention :D

Comment: [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) should give you a warning. It's a must have tool in your workflow. Most editors have plugin to interact with it.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because either I was confused or did not understand something about it and hence wanted some insight form the experts. I agree it could be a silly or even stupid question to ask, but then simply down voting tells me nothing. A down vote is fine , however a reason will be much appreciated !!

Comment: This question *does* show research effort therefore it shouldn't be downvoted. However, the questions might be too board and be closed by people.

Comment: To answer this, a method or tool as to be recommended and that is offtopic as it easily becomes subjective and opinion-based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lint](http://jshint.com/) [it](https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/). There are tools that can automatically analyze your Javascript and catch common errors like this.

Comment: +1, I'd suggest using jsHint however. It's configurable, and configurable per function block. You can adjust the strictness based on context.

Comment: Okay, JSHint, then. I don't actually know much about Javascript linting tools; I just Googled it and picked a few tools.

Comment: Most modern IDEs have an inbuilt linter. If your IDE / editor doesn't, it's time to switch.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment operator (`=`) in JavaScript evaluates to the right-side value of the expression, which means that `test = 2` evaluates to `2` and since all values that aren't falsey (`0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `''`, `NaN`) are thruthy by definition, the if condition was entered.

A good practice would be to always use the `===` sign when checking for equality and `!==` for inequality and there are tools that will help you enforcing those rules, like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `if (a === b) {  do stuff ; }`  that's three equals, `===`

In Javascript you often need three equals, `===`, as this requires primitives to have both the same type and value, and will not perform type coercion which, although you don't mention it, can be another source of confusion.

If you leave off an equals, it becomes two equals comparison, `a == b`, which might not work quite as expected if you are a beginner or unaware of the quirks of this comparison in Javascript, but at least is not an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in JavaScript is pretty easy: always use **[strict comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_when_to_use_them)**. This will avoid not only assignment errors, but also some non-intuitive behavior that can come from JavaScript's weak comparison rules.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Didn't see the questioners requirement to avoid this method.

Use strict comparison operator (===). You can also change the order of the values being compared which will fail if you use assignment statement rather than comparison operator.

Fails:

```
var test = 1;
if(2 = test) {
 console.log(test);
}
```

The above code will throw an exception since you can't assign a value to the constant value.

Works:

```
var test = 1;
if(2 == test) {
 console.log(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a = b` is an assignment. Meaning a will equal to b.

`a == b` is a comparison. Meaning does a equal to b.

`a === b` is the same as `==` however no type conversion is done. Meaning does a equal to b, but also is it the same object/type?

Where your going wrong with your code is

```
var test = 1;
if(test = 2) { //this is true, because test now equals 2.
   console.log(test);
}
```

Comment: I am sure that he knows all this already. His question is asking how to avoid this from happening beside using Yoda Conditions.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign something the value returned isn't representative of whether or not the assignment was successful, it actually just returns the right hand side of the assignment (e.g, the `test = 2` in `if (test = 2)` would return `2` which is "truthy" in JavaScript, thus causing `console.log(test)` to evaluate. This can actually be quite useful in certain cases. For example:

```
while ((value = retrieveSomeValue()) !== null) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

The code above continually assigns some variable `value` to the result of some function `retrieveSomeValue`, tests the resulting value to make sure it isn't null, and executes the while body.

To answer your question though: The `===` operator is more easily distinguished from the `=` operator and probably behaves more like what you would expect out of `==`. [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)